# Form group não atualiza template angular

Tags: angular

Estou usando formgroup e preciso preencher os campos do meu formgroup recebendo dados de um array.

Tentei algo como:

Meu Form Group:

```
produtoForm = this.fb.group({
    nomeproduto: [''],
    valorcompra: [null],
    valorvenda: [null],
    skuprincipal: [''],
    indicepersonalizado: [null],
    ean: [''],
    gtin: [''],
    marca: [''],
    estoque: [null],
    prazoproducao: [''],
    altura: [null],
    largura: [null],
    comprimento: [null],
    peso: [null],
    linkfoto1: [''],
    linkfoto2: [''],
    linkfoto3: [''],
    linkfoto4: [''],
    linkfoto5: [''],
    linkfoto6: [''],
    video: [''],
  });
```

Eu tenho uma variável produto que contém informações de um produto que preciso jogar nesse formgroup. Tentei algo como:

```
this.produtoForm.controls = produto;
```

Também tentei:

```
this.produtoForm.controls.value = produto;
```

Se eu der um console.log(this.produtoForm.controls.value) meus dados estão lá, porém meu template não é atualizado com os dados.

Exemplo do meu template:

```
<form [formGroup]="produtoForm" novalidate #f="ngForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="md-form form-lg input-modal">
          <input formControlName="nomeproduto" required type="text" name="nomeproduto" id="nomeproduto" class="form-control">
          <label id="labelnome" for="nomeproduto">Nome do Produto</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Se eu utilizar com [(ngModel)] meu template funciona como esperado, mas recebo um warning de que é depreciativo usar os dois juntos. Como posso emitir essas alterações pro meu template?

@Edit:

Percebi que atualiza o template se eu utilizar desta forma:

```
(<FormControl>this.produtoForm.controls['nomeproduto'])
.setValue(this.produto.nome);
```

Tem alguma maneira de passar todos os valores da minha variavel produto para os controllers existentes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## patchValue

mutiplos valores

```
this.produtoForm.patchValue({nomeproduto: 'Test'});
```

## setValue

valor único

```
this.produtoForm.nomeproduto.setValue('Test');
```

Answer (score 0):

existe uma função que atribui valores de um objeto no formulário desde que o objeto tenha os mesmos atributos do formulário: `this.produtoForm.patchValue(produto);`